# React/Webpack - Migrate from webpack 1 to 4, "webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin"

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Since My React App is using webpack.
I learn from the tutorial which is webpack version 1.13.2

The following webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

    module.exports = {
      entry: {
        app: './client/Client.jsx',
        vendor: [
          'react', 'react-dom', 'react-router', 'react-bootstrap', 'react-router-bootstrap',
          'isomorphic-fetch', 'babel-polyfill', 'react-select',
        ],
      },
      output: {
        path: './static',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.bundle.js'),
      ],
      module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
              presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      devServer: {
        port: 8000,
        contentBase: 'static',
        proxy: {
          '**': {
            target: 'http://localhost:3000',
          },
        },
        historyApiFallback: true,
      },
      devtool: 'source-map',
    };
```

From the config file generate the output (yarn run compile) as following:

```
    yarn run v1.9.4
    $ webpack
    Hash: c9607842bef19b55cdcd
    Version: webpack 1.15.0
    Time: 5051ms
                   Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
           app.bundle.js  86.4 kB       0  [emitted]  app
        vendor.bundle.js  1.95 MB       1  [emitted]  vendor
       app.bundle.js.map  78.4 kB       0  [emitted]  app
    vendor.bundle.js.map  2.34 MB       1  [emitted]  vendor
       [0] multi vendor 112 bytes {1} [built]
        + 859 hidden modules
    Done in 5.40s.
```

So I search and try some webpack 4 options and parameters of splitChunks

```
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: true,
        splitChunks: {
          cacheGroups: {
            vendors: {
              chunks: 'initial',
              test: 'vendor',
              name: 'vendor',
              enforce: true,
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

But I get the following output:

```
yarn run v1.9.4
$ webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js
Hash: 4a04bfab6be9854c92d3
Version: webpack 4.17.2
Time: 4670ms
Built at: 09/12/2018 6:12:39 PM
                                 Asset      Size       Chunks             Chunk Names
  f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1.eot  19.7 KiB               [emitted]  
  89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg   106 KiB               [emitted]  
  e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512.ttf  44.3 KiB               [emitted]  
 fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158.woff  22.9 KiB               [emitted]  
448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb.woff2  17.6 KiB               [emitted]  
                         app.bundle.js   648 KiB          app  [emitted]  app
                             bundle.js  6.05 KiB  runtime~app  [emitted]  runtime~app
                      vendor.bundle.js  2.22 MiB       vendor  [emitted]  vendor
[./src/App.css] 1.04 KiB {app} [built]
[./src/App.js] 5.07 KiB {app} [built]
[./src/constants.js] 188 bytes {app} [built]
[./src/modules/validate.js] 134 bytes {app} [built]
[./src/pages/Books/BookDetail.js] 10.2 KiB {app} [built]
[./src/pages/Books/BookEdit.js] 7.76 KiB {app} [built]
[./src/pages/Books/BookView.js] 4.71 KiB {app} [built]
[./src/pages/Books/Books.css] 1.07 KiB {app} [built]
[./src/pages/Books/Books.js] 16.4 KiB {app} [built]
[0] multi react react-dom react-router-dom react-bootstrap react-router-bootstrap whatwg-fetch @babel/polyfill 100 bytes {vendor} [built]
[./src/pages/Index.js] 237 bytes {app} [built]
[./src/pages/Login.js] 7.59 KiB {app} [built]
[./src/pages/Logout.js] 319 bytes {app} [built]
[./src/pages/NotFound.js] 3.08 KiB {app} [built]
[./src/pages/Signup.js] 7.69 KiB {app} [built]
    + 617 hidden modules
Done in 5.78s.
```

How can I configure webpack configuration file to get the output like webpack version 1 tutorial?

Comment: be aware that the output won't be equally the same. Versions have changed and how webpack optimises everything has changed. You'll get different results, but that doesn't mean they are wrong.

Comment: @PlayMa256, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

    module.exports = {
      entry: ['babel-polyfill', 'isomorphic-fetch', './client/Client.jsx'],
      output: {
        path: './static',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
              presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      devtool: 'source-map',
      devServer: {
        port: 8000,
        contentBase: 'static',
        proxy: {
          '**': {
            target: 'http://localhost:3000',
          },
        },
        historyApiFallback: true,
      },
    };
```

You can leave the optimizations property, if you use `mode:"production"` they are going to be applied by default.

Comment: es2015 is deprecated, use preset-env too.